# Can't locate libraries installed with MacPorts

Tags: c++, macos, macports, phash

I've installed pHash libraries using MacPorts but when I try to compile the example source code I get this error:

```
Fatal error: 'pHash.h' file not found
#include "pHash.h"
```

How can I tell the source code where to find the libraries? (from what I found they are installed in /opt/local)

Comment: You could install the `pkgconfig` port. Since `pHash` appears to install a `pHash.pc` file, you can find include paths with `pkg-config --cflags  pHash` (or `--cflags-only-I`). There are similar options to query the libraries to link with, and their paths.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

MacPorts installs stuff into `/opt/local` so those header files will be in `/opt/local/include`, which is a non-standard directory, as far as the compiler is concerned.

You will need to pass `-I/opt/local/include` to the compiler.  How you do that depends on your build system, however both `make` and Xcode support it.

You will most likely need to pass `-L/opt/local/lib` to the linker too...